# “execle ” difference between linux and embedded linux

Tags: c, linux, embedded-linux

Using x86 platform ,  I want to start my application named myapp  through  this method:`execl("./myapp","");`It's OK! But  failed when I'm using ARM platform + embedded linux. Why ?   Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: According to the man page, you should be using `execl("./myapp", "./myapp", (char *)NULL);`.  What kind of error do you get?  What's the return value from `execl` and what is `errno`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you would like to use `execle` to pass in the same environment that your calling application had, you can use this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
extern char **environ;

/* ... */
execle("./myApp","./myApp",NULL,environ);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your invocation is wrong: `execl()`'s argument list MUST be terminated with `NULL`.

The fact that it works at all on x86 is a miracle ;)